# Index exceeds matrix dimensions on an empty function

Tags: function, matlab

I am having this issue with a function that I have created in matlab. I have variables h = 0.2 and x = (0:h:1)'. 'x' is a row vector with 5 elements. I am using the following function in matlab

```
function d = dplus(fstring, x, h)
d=0;
end
```

whenever I plug the following into matlab

```
dplus('prob4Func',x,h)
```

I get this error "??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions." This makes absolutely no sense since I am not even using the vector 'x' anywhere in the function. Is there some subtlety to matlab I am missing?

Comment: Are you sure it's this line that triggers the error?

Comment: Its the only line that I enter, so yes.

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine. Maybe you have another function named `dplus` in your path?

Comment: Or you have a variable dplus in the workspace.

Comment: It sounds very much like you have a variable called dplus in your workspace. Try clear; h=0.2; x=0:h:1; dplus('prob4Func',x,h); I bet it will work. Just go clear first

Comment: you can see which variables are defined in your workspace by typing
'who'
or, to get more information about whether dplus is a variable (which looks like your problem) or a function, type the following

'which('dplus')'

Comment: @Navan That was it! I used 'clearvars dplus' and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to use  'clearvars dplus' to get it working. Thanks Navan!